# Check OWL Class

Tags: owl, semantic-web, owl-api

Suppose the range of an object property is defined through a class expression. I want to know whether a particular instance of the class can be used in the range of the object property. Is it possible to use the OWL API and check if a particular class is subsumed by this class expression ?

Comment: what means *"can be used"*? in OWL domain and range of properties are **not** constraints, so there will be no violation or something. Instead, those are used for inference.

Comment: and yes, when you use a reasoner you can indeed check whether a class is subsumed by a class expression. That's one of the basic tasks of a reasoner, isn't it? with OWL API you can do anything on the structres of OWL, i.e. axioms, class expression, etc. - clearly, not all functions might be built-in, but all fundamental methods are there. The rest is up to you if something is missing. Docs and examples are online

Answer (score 1):

OWLAPI cannot provide a complete answer for this - an `OWLReasoner` implementation is necessary for complete results.

Given an implementation of `OWLReasoner`, to check entailment you can either list all the subclasses of a class expression and check if the class you're interested in appears in the response, or ask the reasoner if your class of interest is a subclass, i.e.,

```
OWLDataFactory df = ...
OWLClassExpression ce = ...
OWLClass c = ...
OWLReasoner r = ...
OWLAxiom ax = df.getOWLObjectSubClassOf(c, ce);
boolean cIsSubclassOfCE = r.isEntailed(ax);
```